# how to get all the IP addresses that the pc communicating with

Tags: python, networking, wireshark, scapy

I want to sniff all of the network traffic that the pc is using, I want only the IP adresses, not the message itself.
any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please install the Wireshark and start capturing packets:

Refer: https://www.wireshark.org/download.html

**Step – 1: Select correct interface**

You need to choose the interface you're sniffing data from. If you are using wireless router to connect internet, then select the Wi-fi: en0 option.
If you are confused with many options, please remove unwanted connected devices to reduce the options, also open any YouTube video so that you can see the traffic fluctuation on your internet link interface.

[image]

Note that straight line next to interface means no active traffic on that interface.

(Refer below video for detail information: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wB3ku4TSLY)

**Step – 2: Get the list of all IP addresses**

Click on “statistics”

Click on “IPv4 statistics”

Click on “All address”

[image]

You have option to save the result in plain txt, .csv .xml,  .yaml formats.

[image]